# opsrey backpack modifications: eather 55

Tags: gear, backpacks

From these pics, you can tell I've slightly modified [this pack](https://www.osprey.com/aether-trade-55-aether55f20-214).

Something I did recently on top of all this was to remove the lid. That helped a lot with accessing gear and consolidation. At this point, I get that another backpack perhaps may be more suitable for what this setup is maybe converging on, but that's not an option for me ATM. So, I have a question for how to improve this current setup, especially with some now unused straps/buckles...

> > > Image 1 and 2 show the the unused straps that would otherwise be used for securing/tightening to a receiving end on the lid, which is no longer there (for reasons described above). Is there a double or back-2-back receiver for these kinds of buckles? Or, is there another way I can leverage these straps?

**Image 1**
[image]

**Image 2**
[image]

**Image 3**
[image]

Comment: To be clear: you want to connect those two straps? Permanently or in a way you can disconnect them? Either way, I think you're doing some cutting and stitching. Replacing one side with something like this, and a loop on the other, for example: https://www.amazon.co.uk/sourcing-map-Webbing-Adjuster-Backpack/dp/B0BHWK8H1G/ref=asc_df_B0BHWK8H1G/?tag=googshopuk-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=635843740501&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=12682614135906544870&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1007025&hvtargid=pla-1943144578300&psc=1&mcid=bdc5667b75663a1897569d299cb7ede3

Comment: Good question: yes, ideally in a way that's not permanent. That's the reason behind some (imagined) double-receiver for the buckle inserts.

Comment: Since both genders of buckles are available, as is webbing, it is fairly straightforward to create your back-to-back connector strap. You may want to find a friend with a good sewing machine.

Comment: The problem is there are so many very similar but not compatible buckles, so a back-to-back strap might mean replacing the existing ones. That might be doable without sewing.

Comment: @ChrisH - take the pack to the local gear store and try a few. There really aren't that many variations out there.

Comment: @JonCuster the few stores I've found that have such hardware only stock one brand of such clips.  There are many brands, each available in several sizes.  I keep a selection from old kit; when they turn out to be compatible with something else, it's like a miracle.  Note that some combinations can seem to fit, then come apart under tension.  If you've got plenty of kit, try it and see, with different gear manufacturers

Comment: @ChrisH - fair enough, I guess I've had better luck. In the case of Osprey, they will happily provide parts for their packs so I'd start with them (https://www.osprey.com/customer-support/parts-request/).

Comment: Manufacturer spares seems like a very good way to go @JonCuster. Karrimor used to when my kit was made, but it was all done by post back then - and Karrimor's buckles were a custom shape

Comment: When a buckle on my son's Osprey pack failed we sent them a picture of the failed buckle and they promptly sent out 2 replacements for free. So they do have the parts...